# How to get the base URL of the website VB.NET

Tags: url, hostname, domain-name, base-url

I may not be the first person to ask this question but I can't find what I was looking for after looking around. 
I want to get base URL from the URL. I have tried

```
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

It would return me the full URL

```
    http://localhost:59112/Resources/VideoPlayer.aspx?ID=resources1.mp4
```

I would just need until here (e.g.)

```
    http://localhost:59112/
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With a bit more research .. I got what I want from a forum .. this is brilliant solution ..

```
    Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Url ex: http://localhost:59112/Resources/VideoPlayer.aspx?ID=resources1.mp4

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
```

Return: "localhost:59112"

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme & "://" & HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
```

Return: "http://localhost:59112"

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim address As Uri = New Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568530/how-to-get-the-base-url-of-the-website-vb-net")
    MsgBox("http://" & address.Host)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 4 and later you can use -

```
Dim Url as String = Request.Url.OriginalString
Dim Domain as String = Url.Replace(Request.PathAndQuery, "")

Output -
Url = "http://localhost:9898/content/page.aspx
Domain = "http://localhost:9898"
```

Answer (score -1):

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host`

Comment: This only returns the Hostname, sans the Port and Protocol.

Comment: But this is what I want.